# Get value from date input on keypress event

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to get the current value from a date input field in the keypress event? I have used the jQuery .val() function or the straight javascript .value on text input fields in the keypress event without difficulty, but when I try either of these on a date input field (in a browser that supports it, such as chrome), I just get an empty string - apparently the value isn't set until a valid date is entered.

I'm using this functionality to allow a user to enter a date as just six digits, such as 110712, and automatically adding the slashes as they type to make 11/07/12. I could, of course, just use a plain text input, but I like the pop-up date picker the date type field gives me on browsers that support it.

EDIT:
Perhaps I wasn't clear about what I was trying to do. From within the keypress handler attached to a date input field, I want to get what the user has currently typed in the field. For example, if the user has already typed "11" and then types a "0", I want to be able to see that the current value of the field is "11". With a basic text input (or a browser not supporting date input fields), I can call .val() or .value from within the keypress event handler and it will give me a result of "11". In a browser that supports date input fields, however, all I get when calling val() or .value is "".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

Unfortuantely, it would appear that this cannot be done. Consider the input[type="date"] a select where the options are every date in history, rather than a textbox.
http://www.html5tutorial.info/html5-date.php
The above link shows other browsers implementing it exactly this way. Notice that as soon as your textbox has a valid date, .val() gets that value.

you could accomplish a hybrid using both an input[type="text"] and a small input[type="date"]  next to it that dumps its value into the textbox on change.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/WaAcU/ (this doesnt do your validation, just dumps the selector into a textbox)

**Original Answer:**

use the JQuery keypress handler.

```
$(dateField).keypress(function(){
    ...your validation code...
});​
```

trivial example:
http://jsfiddle.net/zUMHr/

Comment: This will attach a function to the keypress handler just fine, but doesn't help with the .val() function returning an empty string when called from within the handler on a date input.

Comment: ah, i follow. The date field only registers a val() for valid dates. Back in a sec!

Comment: looks like you are out of luck for a straightforward answer: http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/08/Quick-FAQs-on-input-type-date-in-Google-Chrome

Comment: the issue is in the way the browser is handling it, and from my probing of the element object, none of its exposed properties contain the text being entered. Looks like the only way is to use an input[type="text"]

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#clickme").keypress(function(event){
    alert(event.timeStamp);
  alert(new Date(event.timeStamp));

    var fullDate = new Date()
console.log(fullDate);
//Thu May 19 2011 17:25:38 GMT+1000 {}

//convert month to 2 digits
//  var twoDigitMonth = ((fullDate.getMonth().length+1) === 1)? (fullDate.getMonth()+1) : '0' + (fullDate.getMonth()+1);

 //  var currentDate = fullDate.getDate() + "/" + twoDigitMonth + "/" + fullDate.getFullYear();
 // console.log(currentDate);
    // $("#clickme").val(currentDate);
//08/11/2012
});
```

[jsfiddle working example](http://jsfiddle.net/SyRtx/14/)

the above example displays the **`current date on keypress event`**

Comment: Yes, that displays the current date. But I want to get what the user entered in a date INPUT box, not an actual date. .val() just returns an empty string if the browser actually supports date input fields.